# i'm having a trouble in python coding to solve

Tags: python

I have problem with coding please help me to solve the problem

question:

my python code should import the input file to find out the frequency of each word in the input file it should appears in the file and write the word in alphabetical order to an output file called word_frequency.txt

code :

```
import string

def itm((a1,b1), (a2,b2)):
    if b1 > b2:
        return - 1
    elif b1 == b2:
        return cmp(a1, a2)
    else:
        return 1

def main_cd():
    input.txt = raw_input("File to analyze: ")
    text = open(input.txt, 'r').read()
    text = string.lower(text)
    for i in string.punctuation:
        text = string.replace(text, i, ' ')
    words = string.split(text)

    counts = {}
    for w in words:
        counts[w] = counts.get(w,0) + 1

    n = input("Output analysis of how many words? ")
    items = counts.items()
    items.sort(itm)
    for i in range(n):
        print "%-10s%5d" % items[i]


if __name__ == '__main__': main_cd()
```

problem :

File to analyze: input.txt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  line 38, in 
    if **name** == '**main**': main_cd()
line 19, in main_cd
    input.txt = raw_input("File to analyze: ")
AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'txt'

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: don't call the variable `input.txt`. Just `infile` or `input` is fine.

Comment: also, you had `main_cd()` on the same line as `if`, it needs to be indented as I've updated in the question.

Comment: @TyrantWave `input` is bad too.  It would shaddow the built in function

Comment: You also don't need to ``import string``. Anything that is a string can have those methods called on it directly. So for example ``text = string.replace(text, i, ' ')`` is just ``text = text.replace(i, ' ')``, ``words = string.split(text)`` is ``words = text.split()``, etc.

Comment: @cmd: Good point. I'm apparently not awake today.

Comment: @aruisdante actually there are some things in the [`string` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html) you might want to import it for, although the OP isn't using any of them!

Comment: @jonrsharpe realized that I had phrased that wrong and edited it as you were commenting ;).

Comment: Did that solve your problem?

Answer (score 4):

You cannot name your variable with a `.` (`input.txt`). Do this instead:

```
file_name = raw_input("File to analyze: ")
text = open(file_name, 'r').read()
```

**Note**: It is better practice to close the file once you are done reading it. This is a better habit to get into:

```
file_name = raw_input("File to analyze: ")
with open(file_name, 'r') as f:
    text = f.read()
```

Here, the `with` statement context manager will close the file automatically as soon as you are done with the `with` block code.

Answer (score 1):

Drop the .txt from your input variable:

```
input_txt = raw_input("File to analyze: ")
text = open(input_txt, 'r').read()
```